Blazorise data grid numeric edit field number of decimals does not match field data type
I have blazorise datagrid in which I have a DataGridNumericColumn for a integer type.
I have EditMode set to inline and I simply followed what is recommended here:
https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/features/editing
But even though the data type of the field is integer, the edit box shows the number in 2 decimals. I tried to use DisplayFormat="0" but it didn't work.

You need to define Decimals="0".

This works. It also shows a numeric up/down control with up and down arrows. Is there a way to set Min and Max values? I tried Min, Minimum etc. They don't work.
